# SAML Configuration for BambooHR

Tags: saml, auth0

I'm trying to setup SAML to SSO into BambooHR, I'm using Auth0 as my IDP. BambooHR requests a SSO Login URL and x.509 Cert from my IDP (which I can easily provide), but I can't find where BambooHR provides the Audience URI and/or callback URI to enter into Auth0.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference you can use the following for BambooHR's Callback URL and Audience:

```
https://{YOUR DOMAIN}.bamboohr.com/saml/consume.php
```